# Making one row many rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some rows like this:

```
 school      4
 hotel       2
 restaurant  6
```

I would like to do have this output like this:

```
 school 1
 school 2
 school 3
 school 4
 hotel 1
 hotel 2
 restaurant 1
 ...
 restaurant 6
```

Is there a MySQL query I can run to output it like this (i.e., the number of rows output corresponds to the number in the second field)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I don't even know where to start. My database knowledge mostly consists of doing extremely simple select statements and relying on phpmyadmin for the rest.  :(

Comment: Why don't you just select the rows, and use loops to generate your output? MySQL is not the right tool to format output.

Comment: @web-nomad i'd be interested to see your simple mysql solution to the problem.

Comment: @pala_ It would be the same as the OP's answer. It's not that difficult, is it.

Comment: that's not a mysql solution is it? since this wasn't tagged `php` and no discussion had been entered into about the environment, your comment  indicated you had a simple mysql only method to accomplish the result. where is it?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't tagged php because the question didn't have anything to do with php. I wanted to just write a simple query without involving any external programming language. But when it seemed not to be easily achievable, I simply chose to solve it with php because I know php better than anything else. I agree that the tone of web-nomad's comments was a bit curt and condescending, both to pala_ and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for JB Nizet for telling me that MySQL would not be able to do this easily on it's own. It inspired me to write this PHP script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"select abbrev,chapters from books");
while ($output = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 for ($i=1; $i<=$output['chapters']; $i++) {
  echo "{$output['abbrev']}$i\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle or PostgreSQL, this kind problem can be solved relatively simple with row generator. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have any simple way to generate rows, you should have to do it manually. You have to create a view.

```
create or replace view generator_16 as
  select 0 n union all select 1  union all select 2  union all
  select 3   union all select 4  union all select 5  union all
  select 6   union all select 7  union all select 8  union all
  select 9   union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
  select 12  union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
  select 15;
```

This view has one column `n` and 16 rows from `0` to `15`. With this view, you can write a query like this:

```
select a.name, b.n 
from t a, generator_16 b 
where b.n <= a.n and b.n > 0;
```

Since the rows of view starts from `0`, there's additional filter condition `b.n > 0` to exclude `0`. If you define a view which starts from `1`, the additional condition would not necessary.

I assume that the number is small (below `16`). If you have to deal the case that the number over 15, then you should define an another view which contains 256 rows:

```
create or replace view generator_256 as
  select (hi.n*16 + lo.n) as n
  from generator_16 hi, generator_16 lo;
```

Then update the query to use `generator_256`.

For more detailed explanation for `generator_16`, `generator_256` views, reading [MySQL Row Generator](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator) would help you.